# How to fetch data from relationship in strapi.js?

Tags: strapi

I have created two `content type builder` which are `category` and `sub-category` respectively. While adding `sub-category` I had define one relationship which is `one-to-many`.

After creating successfully, I found that the basic CRUD API has been created and it works fine.

Now I need to find data like if I pass `category-id` then it has to return me it's all `sub-category` list.

Well, for this I can also write API manually, But I thought that `strapi` provides a feature of relationship though it may have some way to fetch data from the relationship table. In my app, I had set up a project with `MySQL`.

**Expected output:** Need a way to fetch data from a relation without writing custom API. Looking for inbuilt feature of `strapi`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use deep filtering.

Here is the documentation https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/filters.html#deep-filtering

So you will be able to do `/categories?sub-category.id=[your id]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per your answer, it looks like it will return sub-category's id data which I pass. But I need that I just pass category id and in return I need it's all sub-category data.

Comment: Do you want to do a **findOne** action? with `/categories/[your category id]`?
That will return you category data within `sub-category`

Comment: Yes, When I pass category-id, then I need it's all sub-category data in res.